# Is there a website that lists replication code of financial papers?

Tags: r, research, matlab, codes, ox

There are lot of questions on this website related to the replication of the empirical part of financial papers.

I noticed that some (honest) authors provide on their personal website some replication code in order to reproduce their model/simulations. I found ***very*** useful theses sites but they are rare.

So do you know a website that lists some replications codes (or list the links to these codes) ?

Or a website devoted to this end (finance-oriented) that allow us to upload our personal replication code for well-known papers?
I googled with no success but I can't imagine it does not exist.

Comment: seems like a good idea for a QE proposal on area 51

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://replication.uni-goettingen.de/

(The below text was added by Jan Höffler who founded the wiki.)

This site is a replication project for papers, so far mainly in economics but open to any field. It serves as a database of empirical studies, the availability of replication material for them and of replication studies. It can help teaching replication to students.

You can [search by codes of the Journal of Economic Literature and find more than 200 studies](http://tinyurl.com/ReplicationWiki-financial-econ) with [code G for financial economics](http://replication.uni-goettingen.de/wiki/index.php/Category:G_-_Financial_Economics). You will see many of them have program code, and it is indicated [which software was used](http://replication.uni-goettingen.de/wiki/index.php/Category:Article_software_used). As you tagged [r](http://replication.uni-goettingen.de/wiki/index.php/R) ([2](http://tinyurl.com/ReplicationWiki-Finance-R)), [MATLAB](http://replication.uni-goettingen.de/wiki/index.php/MATLAB) ([54](http://tinyurl.com/ReplicationWiki-Finance-MATLAB)) and [Ox](http://replication.uni-goettingen.de/wiki/index.php/Ox) ([1](http://tinyurl.com/ReplicationWiki-Finance-Ox)), click on them to get all studies for which these packages were used. The numbers indicate how many of them currently have JEL code G and clicking on them brings you to the combined searches. Note that not all publications use JEL codes, so you will be able to find more finance studies with a [full text search](http://replication.uni-goettingen.de/wiki/index.php?search=&fulltext=Search&title=Special%3ASearch), [search by keyword](http://replication.uni-goettingen.de/wiki/index.php/Category:Article_keywords), or maybe by [data source](http://replication.uni-goettingen.de/wiki/index.php/Category:Article_data_source). The list of data sources so far is very incomplete, but it's a wiki, anyone can expand it in any direction. You can also [make suggestions](http://replication.uni-goettingen.de/wiki/index.php/ReplicationWiki:Community_portal). And you can [vote (anonymously) which studies should be replicated](http://replication.uni-goettingen.de/wiki/index.php/Help:Replication_relevance_ranking).

Note that the [Critical Finance Review](http://cfr.ivo-welch.info/) has a [special focus on replications](http://cfr.ivo-welch.info/RFP.htm).

Uploading code is also possible at repositories like [GitHub](https://github.com/) or the [Open Science Framework](https://osf.io/) but so far there is no focus on finance there.

[runmycode.org](http://www.runmycode.org/) has data and code for a number of published finance papers but it is meant to be the authors' own material.

Answer (score 2):

You could consider he fairly-recently started [ReScience](https://rescience.github.io/) initiative which has exactly this in mind:

> ReScience is a peer-reviewed journal that targets computational research and encourages the explicit [replication](https://rescience.github.io/faq) of already published research, promoting new and open-source implementations in order to ensure that the original research is [reproducible](https://rescience.github.io/faq).

As far as I know there have not been any finance/quant submissions.